# How to express A > B > C in written English grammatically correctly without mentioning B twice?

Tags: comparison

In mathematics, we simply say A larger than B larger than C. However, that is grammatically incorrect, because there is no verb in it.

In my case,

> A: people who still smoke
>   B: people who used to smoke
>   C: people who never smoked

One way of specifying A > B > C is ...

> A has a higher risk of cancer than B and B has a higher risk of cancer than C.

But considering B is too long and I wonder if there is any way that I can just mention B once.

How about

> A has a higher risk of cancer than B and in turn than C?

Comment: Do you need sentences *specifying* people or just with symbols you gave? A, B, and C

Comment: larger than can be replaced with greater than..

Comment: @MaulikV Either is fine. Provided with symbols, I can transform it by my own.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A is larger than B **which in turn** is larger than C.  For example:

> On average, people who never smoked outlive people who used to smoke,
>   who in turn outlive those who still smoke.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please care to explain? I really think this answer caters to what the OP is asking about.

Comment: Please don't ask "why the downvote" unless the doer has specified herself/himself. +1

Comment: @MamtaD Feel free to ask 'why the downvote?' People ask it all the time.